# Korn shell (ksh) omits closing quote when displaying aliases

Tags: alias, ksh

When displaying aliases in Korn shell (ksh) the closing quote is omitted.
This happens with both predefined and user-defined aliases:

```
>> alias type r l ltr
type='whence -v
r='hist -s
l='pwd; ls
ltr='ls -ltrT
```

Bourne shell (sh) and Bash do show the expected closing quote:

```
>> alias l ltr
l='pwd; ls'
ltr='ls -ltrT'
```

Here's what the alias definitions in my ~/.kshrc look like. It doesn't seem to matter whether single quotes or double quotes are used:

```
alias l='pwd; ls'
alias ll="ls -l"
alias ltr="ls -ltrT"
```

I am running /bin/ksh in MacOS Monterey, Version 12.4
(The same problem appears in earlier versions of MacOS such as Catalina.)

Why does this happen?  Is this a known bug?  Is there away to correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Where are those aliases defined? If it's in a file, does the file have \r\n line endings?

Comment: What version of ksh are you using?

Comment: Apple ships the last released ksh93, u+2012-08-01.  I would recommend that anyone interested in ksh93 check out [ksh93u+m](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh), which fixes many many bugs.  I can't reproduce this behavior in either ATT ksh93 or in ksh93u+m.

Comment: @glennjackman That's a very good question. The aliases are defined in my ~/.kshrc.  The lines have \n endings (i.e. line feeds but not carriage returns).

Comment: @QuartzCristal I'm running Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01.   Thanks.

Comment: @KS_on_StackExchange Then I have no idea why you are getting problems. Not even with lines ending on `\r\n` am I getting any problem. Good luck.